# Combinatorics - Q Calculus Pascal's Identity Proof

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, quantum-calculus

[image]

I have been trying to get started on this simple combinatorics proof. This has led me to start a proof by induction using pascal's identity from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Analogs_of_Pascal's_identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Analogs_of_Pascal%27s_identity). Not sure where to go from there

Comment: You re-post here a question you have asked only 3 hours ago [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282405) without any mention of it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry.. I was reposting with what I tried